# Перенаправление действий в окно другой программы (игры)

Tags: c#

Как можно перенаправить действие программы в другую?

К примеру, у меня эмулируются нажатия клавиш. Как можно сделать так, чтобы они эмулировались лишь в отдельном окне? Типа, если открыть браузер и игру - чтобы действия сказывалишь лишь на игре, а я мог спокойно лазить в браузере?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, что-бы на него ответить, покажите что вы уже сделали! Конечно, если хотите что-бы вам ответили.

Comment: Можете через сокеты отправлять ваши пакеты с действиями.

Comment: Используйте WinAPI-функции `SendMessage/PostMessage` (информации, как это делать - море). Или используйте такие скриптовые языки, как AutoIt, AutoHotKey для написания ботов.